# php else if condition not executing when testing for empty fields

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I'm trying to test for empty fields and stop them in a simple elegant manner but I can't figure out why this method doesn't work.

```
if($pw != $re-pw)
{
    print "error: passwords do not match";
}
else if($username = "" || $pw = "" || $re-pw = "") //doesn't execute?
{
    print "please fil out all fields";
}
else
{
    //this executes
}
```

I've checked the php manual on if statements, it seems like this should work, but I'm not 100% sure. I'm also not sure if you are allowed to test if a variable = "" in php. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I haven't worked on php in years.

Comment: use `==` for comparison, instead of `=` in `else if($username = "" || $pw = "" || $re-pw = "") `

Comment: oh damn I thought that was changed in php for some reason. back to intro programming mistakes... >.<

Comment: First, use == not =. Second, change else if (second) block as the first condition, because $pw will always be equal to $re-pw when both are not filled. Third, if any character such as space sent with your form (may have the value of " ") that will be not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not answer this question if other answers were complete.

First of all; you are checking if `$pw` is not equal to `$re-pw`, this will be always true if both are null. So, this can be the second condition block; switch if to else if. So;

```
if($var1 == "" || $var2 == "" || $var3 == "") {

} else if($var1 != $var2) {

} else {

}
```

But i would not set those variables, just use the $_FORM["field"] for a better performance. If there is any reason to you should set variable, i would go for `$form = $_FORM` or `$form = $_FORM["register"]`.

So if you go with the `$form = $_FORM["register"]` you have to set your form field into an array.

```
<form id="login-form" action="login.php" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="register[email]" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input type="email" name="register[password]" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="email" name="register[passwordRepeat]" placeholder="Password Repeat">
</form>
```

After all, i could iterate the form array to control if any fields are empty. (Optional)

```
foreach($form as $field => $value) {
    if(empty($value))
        // bla bla bla
}
```

But the short answer is;

> Use `==` instead of `=`. 
>   Consider using `trim($var)` function to anyfields that necessary.  Look for isset and empty functions here:
>   http://php.net/

Answer (score 1):

Use **==** instead of **=**.

**Explaination**: single equal is use for assign a value to a variable and == is use for compare.

**Try this:-**

```
if($pw != $re-pw)
{
    print "error: passwords do not match";
}
else if($username == "" || $pw == "" || $re-pw == "") //doesn't execute?
{
    print "please fil out all fields";
}
else
{
    //this executes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual dictates that for comparison of equality you need to use `==`. what you are doing is assigning a blank value to the variable by using the assignment operator `=`.

So your code would be

```
if($pw != $re-pw)
{
    print "error: passwords do not match";
}
else if($username == "" || $pw == "" || $re-pw == "") //doesn't execute? (changed from = to ==)
{
    print "please fil out all fields";
}
else
{
    //this executes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by only `if(!$variable)` that check variable not null, not false and not empty string.

```
if($pw != $re-pw)
{
    print "error: passwords do not match";
}
else if(!$username || !$pw || !$re-pw) //doesn't execute?
{
    print "please fil out all fields";
}
else
{
    //this executes
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? !$variable will not check for if it has the value or not.

Comment: It's worked for empty string and null, you can test it! @ImmortalDude

Comment: @MohammadHamedani and spaces?

Comment: Space is a character and not empty string, so `if(!$variable)` return false. If you can check not spaces only, you can use `if(!trim($variable))`.